# How to change the array values?

Tags: php, array

My data is in this format. I want it without `wishlist_id`, means simple values. How to change the array values?

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 35 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 36 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 38 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 39 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 42 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 43 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 45 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 48 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 50 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 52 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 53 ) 
    [11] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 55 ) 
    [12] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 57 ) 
    [13] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 59 ) 
    [14] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 60 ) 
    [15] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 63 ) 
    [16] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 66 ) 
    [17] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 67 ) 
    [18] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 69 ) 
    [19] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 70 ) 
    [20] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 73 ) 
    [21] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 75 ) 
    [22] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 76 ) 
    [23] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 78 ) 
    [24] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 80 ) 
    [25] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 83 ) 
    [26] => Array ( [wishlist_id] => 85 )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<pre>';
$twoDimensionalArray = array(array('wishlist_id' => 35),array('wishlist_id' => 40),array('wishlist_id' => 50));
$oneDimensionalArray = array_map('current', $twoDimensionalArray);
print_r($oneDimensionalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

get values by

```
foreach ($wardrobe_ids as $item){
        echo $wishlist = $item[wishlist_id];
    }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: $wardrobe_ids = $mysql->getAll("Select `wishlist_id` from  `customer_wishlists` where `type`='wardrobe'");
 print_r($wardrobe_ids); I am using this

Comment: 'print_r($wardrobe_ids->getData());' use this.

Comment: its giviing me error

Comment: check updated answer this will help you.

Comment: i need it without loop

Comment: Any way to solve this?

Comment: no without loop i haven't shown any solution so...bt can be possible if other has better answer.